# Problem while hitting ENTER Key in Android Studio, Instead of creating a fresh line, it creates sub-lines

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, enter

I don't know what I pressed while I was typing, but all of a sudden I can no longer create new lines.

Whenever I press enter, this happens

```
        Whenever I press Enter
            Instead of creating a fresh Line
            It comes out like this instead
        I would greatly
            appreciate
            any kind
                    of Help
                            That I get
            Thank you
```

Whereas before, I could write like this

```
    ItemTV1 = findViewById(R.id.itemOneTextview);
    ItemTV2 = findViewById(R.id.itemTwoTextView);
    ItemTV3 = findViewById(R.id.itemThreeTextView);
    ItemTV4 = findViewById(R.id.itemFourTextView);
    ItemTV5 = findViewById(R.id.itemFiveTextView);
```

I've tried searching for other answers, but the ones I found consisted of pressing the insert key, which doesn't seem to be the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look in the settings. Look for "Keymap". There you can define any action for every key, and any key(combination) for every action.
The searchbar in the Settings is you friend. It works very well. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already looked into Keymap and still have found no solution to this problem.